# Set max file size for FileUpload control

Tags: file, upload

I need to set max file size 4 MB on FileUpload control. I don't want to use web.config, because size of file is page specific.

Can I get file size by Using Class `FileUpload.FileBytes or FileUpload.FileContents.Length` and calculate size in megabytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

> FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4194304 //4 MB converted to
>   bytes